# How to define an auto-increment number for LDAP structure?

Tags: ldap, auto-increment

I have one attribute (groupIDNumber), I want to make it work as auto-increment number?

How can we define that attr?

Thank for your help,

-nm

Comment: I don't think you can do that - LDAP has no concept of "auto-increment"

Answer (score 4):

[This blog](http://www.rexconsulting.net/ldap-protocol-uidNumber.html) suggests that you can achieve the equivalent by creating a new object that is sort of a sequence. A working implementation in OpenLDAP is reported [here](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201112/msg00245.html). The object is defined as follows (note: not my code, just reproducing what was reported):

```
----------------------------------------------
objectClass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.599
    NAME 'uidNext'
    SUP top STRUCTURAL
    MUST ( cn $ uidNumber ) )
----------------------------------------------
```

LDIF entiries are then written as:

```
--- increment.ldif ------------------------------- 
dn: cn=uidNext,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
increment:uidNumber
uidNumber: 1
-
---- EOF ------------------------------------------
```

[And called with](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201112/msg00241.html):

```
$ ldapadd -x -D "cn=Admin,dc=example,dc=com" -wsecret -f ./autoinc.ldif
```

Comment: Not recommended. The LDAP should not control it for various reason. And thus LDAP RFC do not define the same for posix accounts.

Comment: @BalajiBoggaramRamanarayan useful to know, but what do you suggest as an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

This is not part of the LDAP protocol, nor is it a standard thing to do. It is something you would normally do in your client-side logic. However, depending on which LDAP server you are using, it may be possible to achieve using a plugin or extension.